# Arc length of natural log function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am currently trying to find the arc length of $f(x)=ln(x)$, which involves the integral
$$\int \sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}dx$$
I managed to solve the integral correctly but I want to know if there is a simpler way as I ended up canceling two terms later on.

For reference this is what I did:
$$\int \sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}dx$$
$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx$$
$$u_1=\frac1x$$

$$du_1=-\frac{dx}{x^2}$$

$$v_1=\int \sqrt{x^2+1}dx$$

$$v_1=\frac12(sinh^{-1}(x)+x\sqrt{x^2+1})$$

$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=\frac{sinh^{-1}(x)+x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2x}+\frac12\int\frac{sinh^{-1}(x)}{x^2}dx+\int\frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx$$
$$\frac12\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=\frac{sinh^{-1}(x)+x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2x}+\frac12\int\frac{sinh^{-1}(x)}{x^2}dx$$
$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=\frac{sinh^{-1}(x)+x\sqrt{x^2+1}}x+\int\frac{sinh^{-1}(x)}{x^2}dx$$
$$u_2=sinh^{-1}(x)$$
$$du_2=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$v_2=\int\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
$$v_2=\frac1x$$
$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=\frac{sinh^{-1}(x)}x+{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-\frac{sinh^{-1}(x)}x+\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx={\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$t=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$
$$t^2-1=x^2$$
$$dt= \frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}} dx$$
$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx={\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\int\frac x{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$
$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx={\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\int\frac{dt}{t^2-1}$$
$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx={\sqrt{x^2+1}}-tanh^{-1}(t)+C$$
$$\int \frac1x\sqrt{x^2+1}dx={\sqrt{x^2+1}}-tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{1+x^2})+C$$
Is there a simpler way to do this question instead of what I did?

Comment: Trying a trig sub of $x = \tan\theta$ might be better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arc length of logarithm function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389781/arc-length-of-logarithm-function)

Answer (score 1):

Standard ways to find this integral are to substitute $x=\tan\theta$ or $x=\sinh t$.

You can also let $\frac{1}{x}=\tan\theta$, so $x=\cot\theta$ and

$\displaystyle\int\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\;dx=\int\sec\theta\big(-\csc^{2}\theta\big)d\theta$.  $\;\;$Then letting $u=\sec\theta, dv=-\csc^{2}\theta d\theta$ gives

$\displaystyle\sec\theta\cot\theta-\int\sec\theta d\theta=\csc\theta-\ln\lvert\sec\theta+\tan\theta\rvert+C=\sqrt{x^2+1}-\ln\bigg\vert\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}{x}\bigg\vert+C$